# Issues with visibility of full configuration's vars in subproject's build.sbt

Tags: sbt

This is how our project structure is

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── client
│   └── build.sbt
├── project
│   └── Build.scala
└── worker
    └── build.sbt
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
object Dependencies {
   val slf4jApi = slf4jGroup % slf4jModule("api") % slf4jVersion
   val elasticSearch = "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "0.90.7"
}
```

**worker/build.sbt**

```
import Dependencies._

distJvmOptions in Dist := "-Xms256M -Xmx1024M"

outputDirectory in Dist := baseDirectory.value / "target/dist"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  slf4jApi,
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "0.90.7"
)
```

The dependencies in the `worker` project are not getting resolved and I get the following error:

build.sbt:1: error: not found: object Dependencies
import Dependencies._
       ^

I think the `build.sbt` in `worker` project doesn't have visibility to the `Dependencies` object in `Build.scala` but I am not sure how to overcome this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What SBT version is this?

Comment: As my answer was approved (thanks!), I however don't know, what the issue was in your configuration? Have you figured it out? Would you mind sharing?

Comment: so the issue was gen-idea was not generating sources in all the sub projects/modules...I had to go into each and every module and generate the sources individually..I also deleted the whole project from intellij and reimported it again..

Comment: I don't follow...how could `gen-idea` influence visibility of full build configuration's vars?! When exactly did you face `build.sbt:1: error: not found: object Dependencies import Dependencies._ ^`? Could you show the steps that ended up with the error message? I don't understand when `gen-idea` stepped in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration worked fine for me and although I don't point an issue in yours I show it here as a reference.

Since `client` is of no interest to solve this particular issue, let's leave it out (although it's defined in `build.sbt` below - no `build.sbt` for `client` was defined).

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
   val slf4jApi = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5"
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val client, worker = project
```

**worker/build.sbt**

```
import Dependencies._

libraryDependencies += slf4jApi
```

With the configuration, `sbt` shows:

```
[project-build]> sbtVersion
[info] worker/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.1
[info] client/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.1
[info] project-build/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.1
[project-build]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/project-build/
[info]     client
[info]   * project-build
[info]     worker
[project-build]> show worker/libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5)
```

Could that be that you're using an older version of SBT (pre-**0.13**)?